# How to download a .txt file from a django project

Tags: django, download

I find difficulty on how to download my .txt file after pressing the button which calls the view  respnosible for that.

My .txt file is created locally in the path where my manage.py file resides.

snippet code of my view:

```
file_name= open("example.txt","w+")
file_name.write("\r\n\r\n%s%s%s%s%s" % (var1,"  ",var2,"   ",var3))

response = HttpResponse(file_name, content_type="text/plain,charset=utf8")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(file_name)

file_name.close() 
return response
```

**What i have to change to be able to download my .txt file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your view:

```
    # to write to your file
    file_name = open("example.txt", "w+")
    file_name.write('some text here')
    file_name.close()

    # to read the content of it
    read_file = open("example.txt", "r")
    response = HttpResponse(read_file.read(), content_type="text/plain,charset=utf8")
    read_file.close()

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}.txt"'.format('file_name')
    return response
```

Comment: it works. I had to add the read section and fix my response part.